# Distributed Resource Allocation Architecture

Tags: service, kubernetes, scheduling, distributed-computing, orchestration

I am currently working on scaling a large scale infrastructure that involves distributing complex calculations over a calculation farm (Cluster with a limited number of machines). The current system is based on a service oriented architecture, whereby a limited number of services runs on each machine in the cluster.

The resources used (*CPU, Memory*) by each request sent these services vary widely depending on the content of the request, **but may be known (*or at least predicted*) in advance**. In other word, it is possible to know, for a given request, the following:

- Time it will take to process the request. (*Can vary from ms to minutes to sometimes hours*)
- Maximum memory required to process the request. (*From a few MB to several GB*)
- Maximum number of cores required to process the request. (*Mostly mono-threaded, but sometimes multi-threaded*)

Our current architecture is problematic because our 'scheduler' does not take any of those parameters into account. Because of this, we often run into issues where one particular server is occupied by very expensive/'incompatible' requests (*In terms of memory usage, CPU cores used, etc.*), so processing each of them becomes widely inefficient, while other servers are occupied by relatively 'cheap' requests.

We would like to optimise this allocation process by moving our current infrastructure to a more modern orchestration system, such as Kubernetes (*or other*). The question I have at the moment is, given those requirements (*Efficient distribution of requests with varying resource requirements - known before processing the request*), what platforms currently available could be a good fit to optimise this type of workflow?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes seems a good fit for that type of workload. Each request could be run as a [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) which would run one or more containers to process the request. These containers can each request a minimum amount of resource they will require ahead of time in their specification and also specify a limit on these resources (e.g. maximum memory and maximum number of cores) and the Kubernetes scheduler can pick a node within the cluster that can satisfy and enforce these requirements.

This will allow you to forget about where the workloads are actually running and focus on making sure you just describe the requirements of each request accurately.

Comment: Is it possible for Kubernetes to take 'hints', describing how much one particular job/request may require in terms of resource - to help with the scheduling? I understand that containers are configured with minimum and maximum memory requirements, but considering our use case, it will be difficult to describe containers for each resource usage scenario.

Comment: In some sense - the way you could do this in Kubernetes would be to create a conservative estimate for how much of a particular resource (e.g. memory or cpu) a particular Job/container may need, but then either put a high limit or no limit at all on that resource (depending on the exact behaviour of the container).

Comment: That way, each container will be guaranteed a certain amount of each resource, but if it happens to need more it can burst above its minimum requested amount to 'spill' into the requests of other containers on the same node (as long as not all the other containers require all of their requested resources). Overcommitting resources like this can really help increase utilisation